# Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, args

```
import math
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
z = float(input())
x2z = math.pow(x, z)
z2 = math.pow(z, z)
y2z = math.pow(y, z)
xy2z = math.pow(x, y2z)
xfabs = math.fabs(x - y)
xzsqrt = math.sqrt(x2z)
print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(x2z), (xy2z), (xfabs), (xzsqrt))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(x2z), (xy2z), (xfabs), (xzsqrt))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Looking for help figuring out what I'm doing wrong with this, I had it outputting a minute ago but now I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` call only uses `x2z` as argument. The full expression is

```
'{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(x2z)
```

The remaining variables are passed as arguments to `print`.

You should pass the variables as arguments to `format`:

```
'{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(x2z, xy2z, xfabs, xzsqrt)
```